# Cannot catch stacktrace of Current domain_UnhandledException System.UriFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, stack-trace, unhandled-exception

My app crashes in some periods on one device with following error by  Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.

The problem is that i cannot find specific method causes this. And its crashes only on 1 device in some German Network Area. Stack Trace is showing only following message :

```
Current domain_UnhandledException. Stack trace: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at HttpServer.HttpClientContext.OnRequestLine(Object sender, RequestLineEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at HttpServer.Parser.HttpRequestParser.OnFirstLine(String value)
   at HttpServer.Parser.HttpRequestParser.Parse(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at HttpServer.HttpClientContext.OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Can i get some ideas , how can i find the crash source ?

Comment: We need to see your source code, and the actual port number (the subject of the error message) that is causing the problem.

Comment: The crash is in `HttpServer.HttpClientContext.OnRequestLine`, which attempts to create an invalid URI. Now, which `HttpServer` are we talking about here? It can't be the `HttpServer` present in `System.Web.Http`, as that doesn't include an `HttpClientContext` property. What platform is your code running on, what kind of application is it?

Comment: Source code will not help because is a huge App - that is working as a service for a wpf player.

App is x86, and is running on Windows 7.

I think the problem is in Assembly HttpServer.dll, v1.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Found new details from : https://github.com/duplicati/httpserver/blob/master/HttpServer/HttpClientContext.cs

```
private void OnRequestLine(object sender, RequestLineEventArgs e)
        {
            _currentRequest.Method = e.HttpMethod;
            _currentRequest.HttpVersion = e.HttpVersion;
            _currentRequest.UriPath = e.UriPath;
            // Initialize _currentRequest.Uri to a synthesized path. This will be the final value if the host header is not sent
            string authority = _localEndPoint.Address.ToString();
            if (_localEndPoint.Port != 80) authority += ":" + _localEndPoint.Port;
            _currentRequest.Uri = new Uri((IsSecured ? "https://" : "http://") + authority + e.UriPath);
        }
```

Comment: This code fails on IPv6 addresses, which might be your problem. For IPv6 addresses, the address part has to be surrounded with brackets [] in order to include the port number, which this code fails to do.

Comment: Good Idea ! How can can i avoid this , if my HttpListeners are created dynamically ?((

Comment: Either contact the author and have them fix their damn code (or throw in a pull request yourself), or ask your network guys to set up an IPv6 to IPv4 tunnel, explaining that your application is broken with regards to IPv6. Anything beyond that requires that you rewrite your application logic, which is a little beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for advices ;)